# How can i upload image in database using Spring and REST api?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, rest, controller

I have read a lot tutorials on how to upload image using Spring, but they are all through the form, what if i want to upload image using rest?

This is my html page:

```
   <body>
    <div id="add-movie-form-div">    
        <label>Name</label> <input type="text" id="name-input"> 
        <label>Description</label> <input type="text"  id="decription-input"> 
        <label>Length</label> <input type="text" id="length-input"> 
        <label>Release date</label> <input type="text" id="release-date-input"> 
        <label>Upload picture</label>  <input type="file" id="image-input">                       
        <button id="add-movie-btn">Add</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery/insert-movie.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is JQuery:

```
 let insertButton = $("#add-movie-btn");

    insertButton.on('click', function () {
    let selectTag = $("#item-selected option:selected").text();
    let nameInput = $("#name-input").val();
    let descriptionInput = $("#decription-input").val();
    let lengthInput = $("#length-input").val();
    let releaseDateInput = $("#release-date-input").val();

let movie = {
    "name": nameInput,
    "length": lengthInput,
    "releaseDate": releaseDateInput,
    "description": descriptionInput
};

$xhr = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/create",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(movie),
    success: success,
    error: error
 });
});
```

And i have simple RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MovieRestController {

@Autowired
MovieRepository movieRepo;

@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = "application/json")
public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
    return movieRepo.save(movie);
}
```

Code like this works fine, but how should i proceed if i want also to upload a picture in MySQL db?

Comment: I don't really understand why you're opposing REST and forms? When you submit a form, you create an HTTP request that can be handled by your REST controller to create a new ressource. If you prefer to write the HTTP request with JQuery, then why don't you create a POST request with a multipart/form-data contentType to behave like a form POST instead of application/json? And write a controller like this one : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: @Fabien How can my REST controller handle forms?

Comment: The link in my comment above explains how to do that. You'll find a lot of tutorials with a quick google search. eg : https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/
You just have to use a MultipartFile parameter in your controller @Post method.